# Why when i am pushing my custom Pair class into Queue Interface this is returning 0;

Tags: java, algorithm, data-structures, queue, key-value

```
class Pair{
    int a; int b;
    Pair(int a, int b){
        a=a;
        b=b;
    }
}
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Queue<Pair> a = new LinkedList<>();
        a.add(new Pair(10, 20));
        System.out.println(a.peek().a + " " + a.peek().b);
    }
}`
```

**Why when i am entering my custom based class Pair in a queue which has a parametrized constructor and the object is initialised before putting inside the Queue it is still showing 0, 0 when i am trying to print it.**

Comment: The constructor should use `this.a = a; this.b = b`;

Answer (score 0):

The fault is in your constructor, as you are working only with the passed parameters `a` and `b` and you aren't initializing the `a` and `b` variables of the class instance, so they initialize as `0`.

The constructor should look like this:

```
class Pair{
    int a, b;
    Pair(int a, int b){
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> ‘this’ is a reference variable that refers to the current object.

when you are assigning values without **this** keyword, it doesn't refers the object's variable, rather it refers to the same parameterized variable.

therefore,

```
Pair(int a, int b){
    a=a;
    b=b;
}
```

actually, not pointing to the class variable.

using of **this** keyword, will help you to refer the class variable and assign the value in class variable.